# How can I convert a Pandas column to be all of the same timezone?

Tags: pandas

I have two columns in a pandas dataframe that have datetimes loaded from a Postgresql database. In each column there are datetimes with varying timezones. How can I convert these to datetimes to be of the same timezone?

Comment: How do you know which timezone a time is from?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the columns are timezone aware, you can use

```
for column in df.columns:
    df[column] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df[column]).tz_convert(tz)
```

where `tz` is the time zone you want.